# Need javascript with intents when working with the discord.js library

Tags: javascript

here is the code for a program that should play music from youtube in discord:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('youtube-search');

const token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // ds token

const client = new Client({
intents: [
GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
]
});

const opts = {
maxResults: 5,
key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  // youtube api
type: 'video',
};

let dispatcher = null;
let repeat = false;

client.once('ready', () =\> {
console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) =\> {
if (message.author.bot) return;

const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

if (message.content.startsWith('!play')) {
    if (!voiceChannel) {
        return message.channel.send('Вы должны находиться в голосовом канале, чтобы проиграть            музыку!');
    }

    const searchQuery = message.content.replace('!play', '').trim();

    try {
        const results = await ytSearch(searchQuery, opts);
        const videoURL = results[0].link;
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const stream = ytdl(videoURL, { filter: 'audioonly' });
        dispatcher = connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 });

        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            if (repeat) {
                dispatcher = connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 });
            } else {
                voiceChannel.leave();
                dispatcher = null;
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send('Произошла ошибка при воспроизведении музыки!');
    }
}

if (message.content === '!stop') {
    if (dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.end();
        dispatcher = null;
        voiceChannel.leave();
    }
}

if (message.content === '!skip') {
    if (dispatcher) {
        dispatcher.end();
        dispatcher = null;
    }
}

if (message.content === '!repeat') {
    repeat = !repeat;
    message.channel.send(`Режим повтора воспроизведения: ${repeat ? 'Включен' : 'Выключен'}`);
}

});

client.login(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx);
```

the error it's giving:
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: GatewayIntentBits is not defined
at  (file:///G:/All_Code/bots/bot_discord_music.js:9:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at  (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)

help fix the problems to make the code work please!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `GatewayIntentBits`.

Replace your first line with this:

```
const { Client, Intents, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
```

Comment: nothing has changed :(

Comment: @BelenciucNichita The error should have changed. Or you did not save the file (or you are starting the wrong file)

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it didn't fix the error. could there be a problem somewhere else

Comment: @BelenciucNichita the error should have changed, at least the stack trace. Or you did not properly apply the changes. With the first line edited, you *cannot* have the same error.